# Datetime Variables issues

Tags: pandas, datetime, type-conversion

I have a variable which is a DateTime variable. From that, I get the weeknumber. Afterwards, I want to change the format of the Datetime variable, but then an error occurs to my weeknumber:

1st code

```
df['startedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startedAt'], errors='coerce')
df['endedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endedAt'], errors='coerce')
df['Weeknum_start'] = df['startedAt'].dt.week
```

2nd code

```
df['startedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startedAt'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
df['endedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endedAt'], errors='coerce')
df['Weeknum_start'] = df['startedAt'].dt.week
```

The first code is without affecting the way I have my datetime written. Which is: 2019-11-20 01:04:18
However when I change it to the second format I get the following error: **AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values**

I tried to change the variable and do the command after I get the weeknumber but it does not work. The initial way I have the variable written is: 2019-11-20 01:04:18   but I want it to be different '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', but then my weeknumber does not work

Answer (score 0):

It is expected, because after `.dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')` values in column `startedAt` are not datetimes, but strings.

If want remove minutes, set them to `0` by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df['startedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startedAt'], errors='coerce').dt.floor('T')
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 12:45:12', periods=10, freq='20T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'startedAt': rng, 'a': range(10)})  

df['startedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startedAt'], errors='coerce').dt.floor('T')
print (df)
            startedAt  a
0 2017-04-03 12:45:00  0
1 2017-04-03 13:05:00  1
2 2017-04-03 13:25:00  2
3 2017-04-03 13:45:00  3
4 2017-04-03 14:05:00  4
5 2017-04-03 14:25:00  5
6 2017-04-03 14:45:00  6
7 2017-04-03 15:05:00  7
8 2017-04-03 15:25:00  8
9 2017-04-03 15:45:00  9
```

Comment: can I have the startedAt values in the format I want but not as strings?

Comment: @Vasilis - If want working with some datetimes functions, you cannot use `dt.strftime`, because it convert datetimes to strings and all datetimelike function failed...

Comment: I know but then how can I still have it in datetime type and have it in this format:  %d-%m-%Y %H:%M'